# Run HIVE on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, hiveql

I wants to run `SQL` queries on `S3` files/bucket through `HIVE`. I have no idea about how to do setup. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You first create an `EXTERNAL TABLE` that defines the data format and points to a location in Amazon S3:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_export(a_col string, b_col bigint, c_col array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION 's3://bucketname/path/subpath/';
```

You can then read from the table using normal `SELECT` commands, for example:

```
SELECT b_col FROM s3_export
```

Alternatively, you can use [Amazon Athena](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) to run Hive-like queries against data in Amazon S3 without even requiring a Hadoop cluster. (It is actually based on [Presto syntax](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/), which is very similar to Hive.)